Plaid LOGO change (white label concept)
I am a developer integrating Plaid payments into our website. I want to use our company logo instead of the Plaid logo.
How can I change the logo? Is there any documentation available for this, or should I contact support for assistance?

Find the logo file if it's local and replace the file itself as necessary. If the file is remote, then replace with your own local version you can edit and change as you need.

Plaid offers a co-branded consent pane you can use to show your logo alongside the Plaid logo in the Link consent flow. You can enable co-branded consent on the Dashboard Link Customization pane here: https://dashboard.plaid.com/link/privacy-interstitial
Actually replacing the Plaid logo with your company's logo is not possible.
